# Android listview take much time to load

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with custom adapter and its working fine. But it takes more than 15 sec to load data to listview. Please tell me what is the issue and why its taking too much time? Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    boolean index[];
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    ApplicationInfo entry;
    String[] itempkg;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public Listadapter(Context applicationContext, List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplication, PackageManager packageManager) {
        //super(applicationContext,textViewResourceId,installedApplication);
        super();
        this.mContext = applicationContext;
        this.mListAppInfo = installedApplication;
        index = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
        this.mPackManager = packageManager;
        for (int i = 0; i < installedApplication.size(); i++) {
            checkList.add(false);
            itemChecked = new boolean[installedApplication.size()];
            itempkg = new String[installedApplication.size()];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
        //return ((null != mListAppInfo) ? mListAppInfo.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // index = new boolean[mListAppInfo.size()];
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry

        final ViewHolder holder;

        //  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // reference to convertView
            holder.tvAppName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.tvPkgName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.ivAppIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            // holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        holder.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        holder.tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        holder.tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    //   SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    // SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                    //  edit.putBoolean("checkbox_" + position, true);
                    //  edit.commit();
                    // editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxState" + position, true);
                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    // editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxState" + position, false);
                    //  SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    // SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                    //  edit.putBoolean("checkbox_" + position, false);
                    // edit.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public void setItemChecked3(boolean[] items3) {
        itemChecked = items3;
    }

    public void setItemChecked2(boolean[] items2) {
        itemChecked = items2;
    }

    public void setItemChecked1(boolean[] items1) {
        itemChecked = items1;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivAppIcon;
        TextView tvAppName;
        TextView tvPkgName;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you put your data in the listview?

Comment: @ErikMinarini Adapter3 = new Listadapter(this, AllApps.getInstalledApplication(this), packageManager3);
        Adapter3.setItemChecked3(items3);
        apps3.setAdapter(Adapter3);
        apps3.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: Using RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Have a look at the sample code below, hope it helps.

```
public class ViewQuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String TAG = "my_log";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_question);


        mAdapter = new RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionNameViewHolder>() {
            @Override
            public QuestionNameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        parent,
                        false);
                QuestionNameViewHolder vh = new QuestionNameViewHolder(v);
                return vh;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(QuestionNameViewHolder vh, int position) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
                tv.setText(questionNameList.get(position));
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_stars_black, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return questionNameList.size();
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // inner class ViewHolder
    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String questionName = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.msg_go_details) + questionName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Question question = findQuestionFromName(questionName);
            Intent i = new Intent(ViewQuestionActivity.this, QuestionDetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("questionObject", question);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```